# more confident predicting scores than scoring

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Jamie Ryan, willowy 6´ Fab Radio DJ, is more confident **predicting scores than scoring**, and when it comes to girlish pursuits she **prefers to kick to touch**.* ([Blurb on Amazon page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0340837764))

I am not sure how to understand the parts in bold in the sentence above. Shall I understand the first one literally or is it some sort of a wordplay? And what about the second one? Does it mean that that woman has masculine tendencies and that she is quick to lash out?

PS: She prefers to kick to touch. I would write "she prefers to kick to to touch". I prefer something to something else…

Comment: Can you give us more of the context?  Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: Seems to be really slangy.  I could interpret "more confident predicting scores than scoring" as "more into sports than sex", but I'm just shooting in the dark.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Girl-Thing-Sarah-OBrien/dp/0340837764/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1531850850&sr=1-1&keywords=sarah+o+brien+a+girl+thing&dpID=51LZEyKjHWL&preST=_SY344_BO1,204,203,200_QL70_&dpSrc=srch

Comment: "Jamie Ryan, willowy 6' Fab Radio DJ, is more confident predicting scores than scoring, and when it comes to girlish pursuits she prefers to kick to touch. But when suave and sophisticated Steve Lowe joins the team at Fab City, Jamie's interest in the secrets of 'girl-land' is suddenly aroused. She enlists the help of Sophie, friend, boss and resident expert at all things girlie."   OK, yeah, it's "she's a sports-loving woman and uninterested in romance".

Comment: "prefers to kick to touch" looks like an editing mistake.  @bart-leby  "she prefers to kick to to touch" is not correct; you can't use "to to" like that.  We would say "She prefers to kick rather than to touch" or "She prefers kicking to touching."

Comment: Actually, it could also be: she prefers to kick, to touch. But it ain't great, regardless.

Comment: Or *prefers to kick* ***than*** *to touch.* Or possibly *prefers to kick* ***or*** *to touch.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Predicting scores" = predicting the score in football (soccer) games

"Scoring" = having sex

"Prefers to kick to touch" is probably a mistake, it should be "prefers kicking to touching" or something similar. She prefers kicking footballs to touching (boys).

Together they suggest that Jamie is a sporty and football-loving girl who isn't interested in romance. It doesn't suggest that she is "masculine" or "aggressive". However she isn't a "girly girl".

Comment: What "girlish pursuits" involve kicking?

Comment: Well, football for one.

Comment: Isn't that just a pursuit?

Comment: Perhaps, but look at the book that the source of this not-very-well-written blurb. When it talks about scoring or kicking, it means football.